# Building a pandas data frame with a given index from two series

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have two series:

```
foo = pd.Series([1,2,3])
bar = pd.Series([7,6,5])
```

from which I want to build a data frame:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame()
tmp['foo'] = foo
tmp['bar'] = bar
```

Next, I set the index of the new data frame:

```
tmp.index=range(1,4)
```

Ultimately, `tmp` in this way is:

```
    foo bar
1   1   7
2   2   6
3   3   5
```

However, the following shortcut:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": foo,
        "bar": bar
    },
    index=range(1,4)
)
```

yields the following:

```
    bar     foo
1   6.0000  2.0000
2   5.0000  3.0000
3   nan     nan
```

Indexing is correct but the values are NOT. Why is it not the same? The second method works if I set the indexes of `foo` and `bar` upon creation of the series.

Comment: Pandas does everything with index aligning.  Your series have indexes from 0 to 2, hence when manually assemble the dataframe Pandas will align both series and the new index based on those values.  And, your new dataframe will go from 1 to 3, the zero from the series is dropped and  3 is NaN and that converts int columns to float datatypes.  From Pandas docs [data alignment is intrinsic](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures).

Comment: @zipa has already provided a solution for your problem, but I still want to remind you that, in most Python iterate objects, the index starts from 0, not 1.  So in your case, if you change the index from (1,4) to (0,3), this also give you the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go with:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": foo.values,
        "bar": bar.values
    },
    index=range(1,4)
)
```

Comment: Together with @ScottBoston remark the answer is complete.